# Creating jar which includes classpath

Tags: java, bash, jar

I am trying to send my jar file to other people without the need to send multiple jar files to a person for them to run my application.  Is there a way to include a secondary jar file inside of my jar and have it as my Class-path instead of it being in my working directory?

This is my manifest for when i create the Jar.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MultipleLinearRegression
Class-Path: Jama.jar
```

This is how I am creating my jar file

```
jar cvfm MyApplication.jar manifest.txt Jama.jar *.class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and the [Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) you can create an Uber JAR, containing all dependend JARs in one JAR file. There is also a [Shade Plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). *(If you don't use Maven or Gradle, you should really consider to do so.)*

There is an interesting article here: [Creating Executable Uber Jar’s and Native Applications with Java 8 and Maven](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-executable-uber-jar%E2%80%99s)

There are other similar tools like [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=introduction&file=intro).

Answer (score 0):

for creating a jar file, we can follow these steps,

```
1) Class-Path: <lib1.jar> <lib2.jar> <path/lib3.jar>
2) Main-Class: <classname>
3) Place a new line at the end of this file
```

Comment: I can create the jar file just fine, I want to include my classpath inside the jar that I am creating instead of having to include it in my working directory.  Also that's the same as my manifest so that doesn't help me much.